# pushing to a non-storyboard view controller from a storyboard view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have an initial view controller set up in the storyboard, but another one that I want to push to is set up only in code. It is somewhat complicated to try to set up in the storyboard so I don't want to do that. Is there a way to perform a push segue from a view controller that exists on the storyboard to a view controller that only exists in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

Comment: in this case vc is the viewController i want to push to?

Comment: No... the vc is the viewController you want to push. the self.navigationController is the viewController that you want to push to.
If you are already in the navigationController simply call [self pushViewController:vc animated:YES]